# Using KLARNA with Magento via SOAP

Tags: php, soap, magento-1.7

maybe someone can help because at KLARNA they say that this must be a problem of Magento.
We're using Magento CE1.7 and the KLARNA module, and I want to be able to process orders with this payment method automatically via the Magento API. Just like i do this with the others.

If a package is picked up by the carrier, I create a shipment notice and a invoice via the standard calls which are:

```
String sid = mservice.salesOrderShipmentCreate(mlogin,id,ids,comment,1,1);
int stid = mservice.salesOrderShipmentAddTrack(mlogin,sid,carrier,title,trackingNo);
String invId = mservice.salesOrderInvoiceCreate(mlogin,id,ids,comment,"1","1");
Boolean cap = mservice.salesOrderInvoiceCapture(mlogin,invId);
```

If I do this with KLARNA related orders, the Invoice gets created in Magento and activated at KLARNA. But the KLARNA invoice only contains the invoice fee. No items from the Magento invoice 
But if I create a similar sales order and then click 'Create Invoice' manually in the Magento backend, the order is activated at KLARNA with the correct total price and all items included.

So I'm wondering what I do wrong in doing this via the Magento API? Looking at those both invoices in the backend of Magento lets me see no difference.
Many thanks in advance for any help.
-chris-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible. 
But in the KLARNA documentation they say that activating a quote only partially is not possible with the Magento module.
This makes the module useless for us anyway, so i will also have to use the KLARNA php api when completing orders.